# Fiddler makes my chrome have no internet connection

Tags: google-chrome, internet, connection, fiddler

hello every one i have installed Fiddler on my win 10 1809 PC ..  although i have installed the https  certificate  it still doesn't work !!
at the first pic the error is shown 
and at the second one  when i tried to fix it 
 [image: first pic]
[image: second pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working normally after i just checked chrome for updates 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

- Launch Fiddler
- Click menu *Tools > Options*, HTTPS tab, ensure you see "Certificates generated by CertEnroll engine"
- Click *Actions > Reset All Certificates* and wait, accepting all prompts. You might want to select "Decrypt HTTPS traffic".
- Click OK

Source :
[Reset Fiddler’s HTTPS certificates](https://textslashplain.com/2015/10/30/reset-fiddlers-https-certificates/).

---

In the post
[Fiddler causes my Internet access to stop working](https://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-causes-my-internet-access-to-stop-working),
an admin answers:

> 99% of the time, this is caused by running a 3rd-party firewall which
>   is blocking access to Fiddler.
>
> 1% of the time, this is caused by plugging a Windows Phone device into
>   your PC over USB. The Windows Phone team steals Fiddler's default port
>   (8888) from it.

Comment: still no internet connection after starting capturing traffic !!!!!!!

Comment: I added another possibility.

Comment: can this case the problem ?! https://image.ibb.co/dn5PWL/image.png

Comment: Not likely : DNS does not use HTTP or HTTPS, so doesn't go through Fiddler. I would advise as a test to disable your firewall and anti-virus to see if one of them is the cause.

Comment: no it didn't fix it  :(

Comment: Weird. Try to uninstall and re-install Fiddler?

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: It works on my side, but something different is happening on your side. I never encountered a problem with Fiddler on multiple installations, so I'm at a lose to explain it.

Comment: is there any alternative to it ?!

Comment: There is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), which is more comprehensive and more technical. But before trying it, I would suggest to use [TCPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to see if port 8888 is taken over by some program.

Comment: i knew about "Wireshark" but i need a less complex one   ... "use TCPView to see if port 8888 is taken over by some program" no it's not here is the report file [report file !!](https://file.io/XHXDKT)

Comment: True, 8888 is not in use. Have you tried disabling your antivirus and firewall?

Comment: by the way fiddler takes 54648 [image](https://image.ibb.co/fwtO1V/image.png)

Comment: "Have you tried disabling your antivirus and firewall" yes i did it still doesn't work

Comment: These are dynamic ports which are probably immaterial. Have you tried running Fiddler as Administrator?

Comment: yes i did still doesn't work !!

Comment: I'm afraid I have run out of ideas.

Comment: i have even tried Charles  tool but i  am having the same problem !!

Comment: same issue, some of the application I am trying to debug do not even get connected to internet. Also that apps shows throw the notice that certificate is not trusted. I mean yes  certificate is not trusted that we can understand but why it does not allow connection to internet.